# Can I hardcode the password if I have only 1 user for whom I can manually change code now and then

Tags: authentication

I tried to find out whether folks ever hardcode their passwords for web applications that don't really have more than 1 user, but haven't found any yet.

However, this hypothetical situation could be real:  "An application which uses SSL, has one user who can change code anytime, and deploy anytime"

If the developer have the capability to change the code and deploy at-will, would there be a need to:
1. Encrypt the password, and 
2. Store that password (or its hash) in some DBMS.
?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Generally hardcoding passwords is A Bad Idea, but it really depends what you're doing. If you're building something entirely for your own use that is only deployed to your local machine and is firewalled off from the rest of the world then *that* would be a reasonable time to not bother with proper authentication. Otherwise you probably want to do things right.

A few things to think about:

1. Who has access to the source? If anyone other than the developer can see the source then hardcoding the password will be A Bad Thing.
2. How much damage can an unauthorized user cause? If they can cause a lot of damage then don't hardcode the password.
3. Is the web application only available from a single machine? That may mitigate some security concerns.
4. Is your single user the one who can deploy new code? If so, you might as well not bother with authentication because that user can just deploy code that doesn't check the password.

It's usually pretty easy to put in proper password authentication. Just about every web development framework includes support for good password storage (e.g. bcrypt), so why not take advantage of it?